# How to display user data after logged in?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display information regarding the user after they have logged in. After the user has logged in the user will be redirected to success.php. I use `MySQL` and a form is an `HTML` form.

I tried writing the success page in two different ways

**success.php** (1)

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["loggein"]) || $_SESSION["loggein"] == false) {
    include ("getUser.php");
    // header("Location: getUser.php");
    echo "done";
}
```

**success.php** (2)

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["loggein"]) || $_SESSION["loggein"] == false) {
    echo "done";
}
?>

<h2>you have logged in</h2>

<p><?php include ("getUser.php");?></p>
```

I tried to include a file getUser.php that is suppose to retrive everything regarding the user.

**getUser.php**

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_REQUEST['username']);

$sql= "select * from userTable where username = '$username'";
if($result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
        echo "<table>"; 
        echo "<table";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>username</th>";
                echo "<th>city</th>";

            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No user" . mysqli_error($connection);
    }
}
```

I keep getting the "No user" error message from the getUser.php. I do not understand why I get it

Comment: something doesn`t add up here. $connection and $conn, so which one is it?

Comment: its suppose to say connection, must have missed that @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: when logging in, keep the ID of the user in a session variable and use this to get user data whenever needed. 

`$_SESSION["loggedin_id"]`

Comment: @SureshPokharel, so I am using a session, thouge I am not sure how to use it later on. Below is the code that I am using when trying to log in:
  if (isset($_SESSION['loggein']) && $_SESSION['loggein'] == TRUE) {
    header("Location: success.php");
  }

Answer (score 1):

In `getuser.php` you didnt make connection with your database.So add the below line at top of your php document.

```
$connection = new mysqli("HOST_NAME","USER_NAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE_NAME") or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $connection -> error);
```

Comment: Thanks! I added it above the text, must have forgotten to add it to the question. So that wont unfortunately help me with my issue

Answer (score 0):

This more than likely will not solve your issue but I believe it could lead you  closer or help us better understand what is going on. I can't comment yet so I am posting it here and will continue to help you along until we solve the problem.

Add this to the top of your php documents:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

It will write errors to a text document stored on your server to help us debug your issue.

Comment: thank you! I added this to the top of my success.php file. I got the error message: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
refering to the 3th line in getInfo.php

Comment: @jacub I don't see a file there for getInfo.php

Comment: my mistake, its suppose to say getUser.php